# iOS - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios

I wanted to use the following void API to write a captured image to the photo album but I am not very clear about 2 of the parameters

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);
```

From the explanation from ADC:

`completionTarget:` optional; the object whose selector should be called after the image has been written to the Camera Roll album.

`completionSelector:` the method selector of the completionTarget object. This optional method should conform to the following signature:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

What is the significance of `completionTarget` here? Can someone explain with an example how this parameter should be used? Or any resource which can guide me through it.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

- The `completionSelector` is the selector (method) to call when the writing of the image has finished.
- The `completionTarget` is the object on which to call this method.

Generally:

- Either you don't need to be notified when the writing of the image is finished (in many cases that's not useful), so you use `nil` for both parameters
- Or you really want to be notified when the image file has been written to the photo album (or ended up with a writing error), and in such case, you generally implement the callback (= the method to call on completion) in the same class that you called the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function from, so the `completionTarget` will generally be `self`

As the documentation states, the `completionSelector` is a selector representing a method with the signature described in the documentation, so it has to have a signature like:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

It does not have to have this exact name, but it has to use the same signature, namely take 3 parameters (the first being an `UIImage`, the second an `NSError` and the third being of `void*` type) and return nothing (`void`).

---

#### Example

You may for example declare and implement a method that you could call anything like this :

```
- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
    if (error) {
        // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
    } else {
        // .... do anything you want here to handle
        // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
    }
}
```

And when you call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` you will use it like this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage,
   self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
   @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
   NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here
```

**Note** the multiple ':' in the `@selector(...)` syntax. The colons are part of the method name so **don't forget to add these ':' in the @selector** (event the trainling one) when you write this line!

Comment: May you add a Swift version? Pretty please? :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Calling UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in modern iOS and Swift

In modern iOS, there is an additional requirement for using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. You have to include in your *Info.plist* a key `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` ("Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description"). This is so that the system can present the user with a dialog requesting permission to write into the camera roll.

You can then call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in your code:

```
func myFunc() {
    let im = UIImage(named:"smiley.jpg")!
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im, self, #selector(savedImage), nil)
}
```

The last parameter, the context, will usually be `nil`.

The idea of the second two parameters, `self` and `#selector(savedImage)`, is that your `savedImage` method in `self` will be called back after the image is saved (or not saved). That method should look something like this:

```
@objc func savedImage(_ im:UIImage, error:Error?, context:UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let err = error {
        print(err)
        return
    }
    print("success")
}
```

A typical error would be if the user refused permission in the system dialog. If all goes well, the error will be `nil` and you'll know that the write succeeded.

In general, UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum should probably be avoided, in favor of the Photos framework. However, it's a simple way to get the job done.

Comment: How can this be done using photos framework?

Answer (score -2):

**SWIFT VERSION based on AliSoftware solution**

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
    yourImage,
    self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
    #selector(image(path:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
    nil // you generally won't need a contextInfo here
)

@objc private func image(path: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if ((error) != nil) {
        // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
    } else {
        // .... do anything you want here to handle
        // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
    }
}
```