# cordova screenshot plugin cant return image

Tags: ios, plugins, jquery-mobile, screenshot, cordova

I am building an iPhone/iPad app using Cordova/jQuery Mobile. Ive used the following screenshot plugin https://github.com/josemando/phonegap-plugins/commit/4c2ec54ae001ad409e4d4fe6f5ec6b9ef8b7dc3f which works a treat. It captures a screenshot and saves it to my Camera Roll Album. However how can i then get a hold of this image in my Javascript to eventually upload it onto my web server.

I use the following js script to execute the screenshot function, but it doesnt return an image.

```
Screenshot.prototype.saveScreenshot = function() {
    cordovaRef.exec("Screenshot.saveScreenshot");
};
```

This is the Screenshot.m file:

```
#import "Screenshot.h"

@implementation Screenshot

@synthesize webView;

- (void)saveScreenshot:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options
{
CGRect imageRect;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

// statusBarOrientation is more reliable than UIDevice.orientation
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) { 
    // landscape check
    imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetHeight(screenRect), CGRectGetWidth(screenRect));
} else {
    // portrait check
    imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(screenRect), CGRectGetHeight(screenRect));
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, 0);
CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);

[webView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Image Saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this could work!

**UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);**

as Example:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage,
   self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
   @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
   NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here
```

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628764/1322642)

to get an image

```
- (UIImage*)saveScreenshot:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options
....
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

....
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
....

return image;
```