# Access URL of recently saved image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am using the

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
```

to save image but i want to know where it is getting saved, mean referenceURL and name of saved image..

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628048/ios-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using ALAssetsLibrary

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:myCGImage metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) 
{
      if (error.code == 0) {
         NSLog(@"URL %@", assetURL);
          [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
              NSLog(@"Filename %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename]);
          }
          failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
             NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
       }else {
           NSLog(@"saved image failed.\nerror code %i\n%@", error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
       }
}];
```

Comment: How we will get URL, its giving URL = (null) and file name = (null)

Comment: I get this when I run it: 2013-01-24 19:53:31.839 speedClock[18363:907] URL assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=BB9BD7E2-076E-47DC-86B8-8C211C7ADDF3&ext=JPG
2013-01-24 19:53:31.888 speedClock[18363:907] Filename IMG_0990.JPG

Comment: Are you sure that you CGImage is OK and that you have added the assetlibrary framework?

Comment: I have a question.. is "myCGImage" is same as "image" in my example..?

Comment: Ya answer helped me a lot in solving my problem.. Thank you.

Comment: OK fine, but then you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark at the answer! You will find that people at this site are very helpful, but only if you follow the etiquette. See "How do I ask questions here?" and "What is reputation?" in the FAQ.