# Save a photo to the camera roll and make sure it actually saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, save, photo

I am currently saving a UIImage to the camera roll this way.

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalPicture.image, nil, nil, nil);`

But what happens if the user denies us permission to access their photos... how can I tell that this has happened and display an error message?

Comment: Did you try passing in a completion handler and seeing what happens?

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't know there was one :) What's the code for a completion handler? Where would I implement such a thing? :)

Comment: Did you read the docs for `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`?

Comment: Completion handler example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7628048/2057171

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save the image to the camera roll I'm Using ALAssetsLibrary so in the method:

```
//Called after taking the photo with the camera or selected the image from the gallery  
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSURL *referenceURL;

if(Picker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){

    UIImage* takenImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    // Request to save the image to camera roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[takenImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[takenImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
           //NOT SAVED
           //DISPLAY ERROR THE PICTURE CAN'T BE SAVED
        } else {
          //SAVED 
        }  
    }];        

 }
}else{
//Selected from gallery
}
```

Also remember that you have to check first if the camera is available.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        //The camera is available
    }else{
       //No camera available
    }
```

Comment: But would this still work for just saving a UIImage or is this only for having them take a photo with the camera and then saving that?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw If you end up using `ALAssetsLibrary` you can first call `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];` to determine the current status.

Comment: You can use the  ALAssetsLibrary wherever you want to save a UIImage but in this case I'm saving the image that the user take with the camera, so can work both ways. If you want to save a UIImage that wasn't taken with the camera use the same method the only difference is how you get the  UIImage* takenImage=@"myimage.png"; and you don't need the - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info method because your are saving a image from another place.