# iOS - write jpeg file to file system

Tags: ios, file-io, jpeg

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to write an image as a jpeg file to the file system. From the logs I know that those file are indeed written to the file system, but when I try to save them to the camera roll they all appear black. I'm using the following code to write them as jpeg files:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpegPath atomically:YES];
```

And the following code to write to camera roll:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Anybody know how to verify that those jpeg files are indeed written to the file system? And what I might be doing wrong in the second line of code?

EDIT: So here is the entire method:

```
- (BOOL)createImagesForSlides:(NSString *)documentsPath destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    CPDFDocument *document = [[CPDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:destinationURL];
    NSString *folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", document.title];

    // create new folder
    NSString *newFolderPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:folderName];
    BOOL result = [manager createDirectoryAtPath:newFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

    // create a jpeg file for each page of the pdf file
    for (int i = 1; i <= document.numberOfPages; ++i) {
        NSString *jpegPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.jpg", newFolderPath, i];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[document pageForPageNumber:i] image], 1.0) writeToFile:jpegPath atomically:YES];

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([[document pageForPageNumber:i] image], nil, nil, nil);
    }

    return result;
}
```

document is a pointer to a CPDFDocument instance, and it's from some open source reader code available on github (iOS-PDF-Reader). What I basically do here is grab each page of the pdf document, generate an image, and then save them to the file system as jpeg file. Weird enough, even though there are more than 10 pages in the document, `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` only writes 5 files to camera roll. Any idea why?

Comment: FYI - Those two lines of code have nothing to do with each other. You can either one or do both. One has no affect on the other.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you could provide more of the code around `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);` which might give us a hint as to what is causing the problem.

Comment: `writeToFile` returns a `BOOL` to report its result. For `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` you may inform a completion handler (target & selector) to be informed of whether it succeeded or failed. See [iOS - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628048/ios-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)

Comment: It's reporting yes. I also printed all the file names in the directory and they appear to be there @jweyrch

Comment: @ljiatu I mean your code should automatically check the result of those operations (`writeToFile` and `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`).  As it appears in your question, your code is not doing that. Imagine what happens to your application when those operations fail because the device's storage is full. Won't you like to report it to the user?

Comment: Well, I know I should do that, but the problem now is that I want a way to check those files are really there. @jweyrich

Comment: @ljiatu That's what I'm saying - By checking the result of those operations you'll know if those files were saved to the file-system. There's no need for any other verifications. It's either that, or I didn't understand your problem at all.

Comment: Yes it's reporting YES for all operations. I just doubt if it's going to give me a bunch of black pictures.

Comment: @ljiatu, I assume you are using a simulator (which can sometimes cause troubles with things like this, but I have never heard it causing troubles with this functionality), are there any permission settings that you need to set before you are able to save to camera roll. Check `Settings -> Privacy -> Photos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be useful to see how you construct jpegPath here.

First, `writeToFile:atomically:` returns a `BOOL`, so check that for your first indication of success or failure.
There are a couple of ways you can verify that the image is written to the file system. If you are running on a device use something like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/?gclid=CPqY1LXSnb0CFUNxvAodqawAqA) to access the file system and look at the file written. Since it is NSData* you can cheek the file size to make sure it looks reasonable. On the simulator, dig into the folder structure under `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` and examine the file. Without looking into the filesystem itself try reading the image back into another UIImage (`imageWithData:` in your case since you are writing a NSData* object).

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` call according to the docs. It is OK for the last 3 arguments to be nil (all are marked as optional), you just have to be sure the UIImage is valid. Have you set a breakpoint to be sure you have a valid image (Xcode Quick Look feature)?

Comment: Turns out that the image method the library provided is not working correctly. That's why we get a bunch of black images.