# If/Else statement with UIKit Functions in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit, alert, camera-roll

I'm trying to figure out a way to have my iOS app save a screenshot to the Camera Roll and then pop up an alert to tell the user that the screenshot was saved successfully. The only way I can think to do this would be with some form of an if/else loop (as you'll see in my pseudocode comments below), but I can't think of any syntax to work with the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function from UIKit. Any suggestions?

```
func screenshotMethod()
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(HighchartsView.scrollView.contentSize, false, 0);
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil,nil, nil)
    //if saved to Camera Roll
    //            {
    //              confirmScreenshot()
    //            }
    //        
    //else 
    //        {
    //            exit code/stop 
    //        }


}


func confirmScreenshot()
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "This chart has been successfully saved to your Camera Roll.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your question is misleading to what you are trying to do with the description of the question. So you want to know how to know whether UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() saved an image successfully? The best way is to use the selector parameter and grab the NSError from your chosen selector and inspect it. The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628048/ios-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum) has good pointers on how to do that (in Objective-C, which is easily adaptable to Swift).

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) you can see that there is a `completionTarget` and a `completionSelector`, which is some kind of basic delegation (because it is not enforcing some kind of protocol your class has to conform to, to be used as delegation target). For example you would implement a function in you class conforming the specified signature defined by the `completionSelector` and then pass `self` as `completionTarget` and the name of your function as `completionSelector`.

In your case this would be:

```
func screenshotMethod()
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(HighchartsView.scrollView.contentSize, false, 0);
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "didSaveScreenshot:", nil)
}

func didSaveScreenshot(image: UIImage?, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo contextInfo: AnyObject?) 
{
    if let error = error {
        //Not successful
    } else {
        //Success
    }
}
```

Note: I did not test this, but it should work. Only thing is, I am not sure how to port a void pointer from Objective-C to Swift, so everyone feel free to correct me here.